# How to hook code(codeigniter 3) to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, hook, custom-wordpress-pages

I haved make form input on codeigniter 3. I want hook it to plugin wordpress. I just know that place the folder into wp-content-plugin. but i dont know how to hook it. so what shoud i do to make it run? Please help me.

```
function form(){
$this->load->model('m_kode_model');
$data['kode'] = $this->m_kode_model->buat_kode();
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('anggota/form',$data);}
```

Comment: Share your code so that it shows your effort and help others to understand your problem better.

Comment: Hai Shubhamoy Chakrabarty! Thats the function on anggota.php controller. i want to call it to be plugin in wordpress. it mean, it will show in my wordpress page. it will show about form input. how to hook it ??? i used codeigniter 3. http://localhost/data/anggota/form (url shown form input)

function form(){
    $this->load->model('m_kode_model');
    $data['kode'] = $this->m_kode_model->buat_kode();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('anggota/form',$data);
}

Comment: If i understood your question you want WP to use your CI method?

Comment: yes, like integration CI to WP..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because you have written CI syntax for wordpress plugin. It will not work in wordpress. If you want that your code run in Wordpress then you should using custom php for WP plugin..
Or else if need CI code run in Wordpress then you need to put all folders of Ci in WP plugin folder. But i think that should not be the way..

Comment: If I put it (folder of CI) in wp plugin, so what the next step to integration the code with wp ??

Comment: Please go through with this link..
https://www.airpair.com/wordpress/posts/developing-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you want use Codeigniter's Objects and functions in a custom script.
For doing that you need an instance of the Codeigniter's main object (mostly known as CI), you can use functions and classes outside the framework.

This link may help you https://codeinphp.github.io/post/codeigniter-tip-accessing-codeigniter-instance-outside/